# Descargas y solicitudes inesesarias a la Db RealTime Firebase / React js /Facturacion

Tags: javascript

Estoy buscando una solucion a las consultas que estoy realizando a la base de datos de realtime de Firebase. El almacenamiento de la base de datos pesa 1.3Mb lo que es muy poco en comparacion a lo que me estan facturando. En un dia de 5mil visitas a mi web Firebase me esta facturando 10gb de descargas. Envio una porcion de mi codigo en el cual hago las consultas a la DB.

```js
const db = getDatabase();

const starCountRef = query(ref(db, 'Fixture2023'), orderByChild('fecha'), limitToLast(55)); 

const today = moment().startOf('day');

const startOfDay = today.toISOString(); 

const endOfDay = today.clone().endOf('day').toISOString();

const todayQuery = query(starCountRef, startAt(startOfDay), endAt(endOfDay));

useEffect(() => {

  onValue(todayQuery, snapshot => {

    const data = snapshot.val();
    
    if (data) {
    
      const rows = Object.entries(data).map(([id, value]) => ({ id, ...value }));
      
      const groupedData = groupByTorneo(rows);  
      
      setGroupedData(groupedData);
      
      setLoading(false);
      
    } else {
    
      setGroupedData([]);
      
      setLoading(false);
    
    }

  });

}, []);
```